# In a sentence containing adverbs of time, manner, and place, does word order matter?

Tags: traducción, gramática, sintaxis, adverbios, orden-de-palabras

I was recently looking for examples of a particular phrase in Spanish when I came across this sentence [in an article in *El País*](https://elpais.com/internacional/2019/10/09/estados_unidos/1570646213_076701.html):

> **"... 'y ahora estamos lenta y cuidadosamente trayendo a nuestros grandes soldados a casa'".**
> *"... 'and now we are slowly and carefully bringing our great soldiers home.'"*

It got me to wondering about word order.  For example, could this also be written:

> ... y ahora estamos trayendo lenta y cuidadosamente a casa a nuestros
> grandes soldados.

For the sake of full disclosure (if you didn't click on the link above), this quoted material allegedly comes from President Trump.  This is important because, presumably, Trump said this in English and *El País* translated it into Spanish.  So, in addition to my  main question, is this translation one that tries to capture the way Trump said it?  Or does it follow the word order of good Spanish writing?  (It appears to be as close of a translation as possible to how Trump delivered this line, if, indeed, this was how he uttered it.*)

---

`*I didn't hear Trump utter this line firsthand.  When I did a search of "and now we are slowly and carefully` `bringing our great soldiers home" (the translation provided by Google Chrome), I only found`
`one Google hit for it and this was on a site named "We Are Breaking News" (https://wearebreakingnews.com/about-us),` `a site I've never heard of before now.  Regardless, when I look` `at the Spanish and try to translate it into English, that's how I'd translate it, too.`

---

I know in some languages the most important part of the sentence is placed in final position(s).  In some languages (German comes to mind primarily), there is what is called the "Mittelfeld" and so as not to get too into the weeds on it, it's basically the middle part of a sentence where typically you might find adverbs.  Certain rules apply to the order of the various types of adverb (e.g., time, manner, place).

Because this sentence:

> "... 'y **ahora [tiempo]** estamos **lenta y cuidadosamente [modo]** trayendo a nuestros grandes **soldados [complemento directo]** **a casa [lugar]**'".
> *"... 'and **now [time]** we are **slowly and carefully [manner]** bringing our great **soldiers [direct object]** **home [place]**.'"*

contains three different types of adverbs and a direct object, it got me to thinking about the German language and whether or not Spanish shares any similarities with its grammar (a topic of its own, to be sure).

In the sentence above, there are four adverbs — *ahora*, *lenta y cuidadosamente*, and *a casa* each covering time, manner, and place.  In German, the direct object would typically come after all of the adverbs.  Generally speaking (i.e., not when trying to capture the full flavor of another's speech), are there any rules in Spanish governing whether or not an adverb should come before or after a direct object?

I know adverbs typically come after the verb in Spanish and therefore my initial tendency (if I put some thought to it) would be to write this:

> ... y ahora estamos trayendo lenta y cuidadosamente a casa a nuestros
> grandes soldados.
> *"... 'and now we are bringing slowly and carefully home our great soldiers.'"*

which is the same word order I asked about earlier in this post.  I am preferential to this word order but only for the following reasons:

1. I don't break up the verbal phrase (i.e., *estamos* and *trayendo*
   stay together) and the adverbs (*lenta y cuidadosamente* and *a
   casa*), follow the verb.
2. I adhere to the German rule of adverbial placement — time, manner,
   and place. (I'm not sure if that applies, but I have often
   noticed that adverbs of time often "front" a Spanish sentence and it does here, too, with *ahora*.  So, perhaps the others follow suit.)

Having said that, I must admit that *and now we are bringing slowly and carefully home our great soldiers* sounds really awkward in English.  In this particular example, it sounds much more natural in English to put the adverb of place (home) immediately after the verb (i.e., *... we are bringing home ...*) or to split up the verbal phrase (i.e., *... we are slowly and carefully bringing ...*).

If word order in Spanish isn't all that important and I can lay down parts of a sentence in pretty much any order I want (without the one cardinal rule of keeping parts of a verbal phrase together), then am I emphasizing certain aspects of a sentence via my choice of word placement?  For example:

1. > "... 'y ahora estamos lenta y cuidadosamente trayendo a nuestros grandes soldados ***a casa***'".
   > "... 'and now we are slowly and carefully bringing our great soldiers ***home***.'"
2. > ... y ahora estamos **trayendo lenta y cuidadosamente** a casa ***a nuestros
   > grandes soldados***.
   > "... 'and now we are **bringing slowly and carefully** home ***our great soldiers***.'"
3. > ... y ahora estamos **trayendo a casa** lenta y cuidadosamente ***a nuestros
   > grandes soldados***.
   > "... 'and now we are **bringing home** slowly and carefully ***our great soldiers***.'"

Are the three Spanish variations I've listed immediately above grammatically correct?  Do they all sound natural to a native speaker of Spanish?  Does one stand out as the best in terms of word order/construction?

---

**¿En una frase que contiene adverbios de tiempo, modo y lugar, ¿importa el orden de las palabras?**

Recientemente estaba buscando ejemplos de una frase particular en español cuando me encontré con esta frase en [un artículo de *El País*:](https://elpais.com/internacional/2019/10/09/estados_unidos/1570646213_076701.html)

> **"... 'y ahora estamos lenta y cuidadosamente trayendo a nuestros grandes soldados a casa'".**
> *"... 'and now we are slowly and carefully bringing our great soldiers home.'"*

Me hizo preguntarme sobre el orden de las palabras.  Por ejemplo, ¿podría esto también ser escrito:

> ... y ahora estamos trayendo lenta y cuidadosamente a casa a nuestros
> grandes soldados.

Para el bien de la divulgación completa (si no hizo clic en el enlace de arriba), este material citado supuestamente proviene del Presidente Trump.  Esto es importante porque, presumiblemente, Trump dijo esto en inglés y *El País* lo tradujo al español.  Así que, además de mi pregunta principal, ¿es esta traducción una que intenta captar la forma en que Trump lo dijo?  ¿O sigue el orden de las palabras de la buena escritura española?  (Parece ser una traducción lo más parecida posible a la forma en que Trump la dijo, si, de hecho, así fue como la dijo.*)

---

`*No escuché a Trump decir esta línea de primera mano.  Cuando hice una búsqueda de "and now we are slowly` `and carefully bringing our great soldiers home" (la traducción proporcionada por Google Chrome),` `sólo encontré un hit de Google para ello y esto fue en un sitio llamado “We Are Breaking News”` `(https://wearebreakingnews.com/about-us), un sitio del que nunca había oído hablar antes.  Sin` `embargo, cuando miro el español y trato de traducirlo al inglés, así es como lo traduciría también.`

---

Sé que en algunos idiomas la parte más importante de la frase se coloca en la posición o posiciones finales. En algunos idiomas (me viene a la mente el alemán principalmente), existe lo que se llama el "Mittelfeld" y para no meterme demasiado en la maleza, es básicamente la parte media de una frase donde típicamente se encuentran los adverbios. Se aplican ciertas reglas al orden de los distintos tipos de adverbios (por ejemplo, tiempo, modo, lugar).

Porque esta frase:

> "... 'y **ahora [tiempo]** estamos **lenta y cuidadosamente [modo]** trayendo a nuestros grandes **soldados [complemento directo]** **a casa [lugar]**'".
> *"... 'and **now [time]** we are **slowly and carefully [manner]** bringing our great **soldiers [direct object]** **home [place]**.'"*

contiene tres tipos diferentes de adverbios y un objeto directo, me hizo pensar en el idioma alemán y si el español comparte o no alguna similitud con su gramática (un tema en sí mismo).

En la frase de arriba, hay cuatro adverbios: *ahora*, *lenta y cuidadosamente*, y *a casa*, cada uno cubriendo el tiempo, el modo y el lugar. En alemán, el complemento directo se coloca típicamente después de todos los adverbios. Hablando en general (es decir, no cuando se trata de capturar todo el sabor del discurso de otro), ¿hay alguna regla en español que gobierne si un adverbio debe venir antes o después de un objeto directo?

Sé que los adverbios suelen venir después del verbo en español y por lo tanto mi tendencia inicial (si me pongo a pensar en ello) sería escribir esto:

> ... y ahora estamos trayendo lenta y cuidadosamente a casa a nuestros
> grandes soldados.
> *"... 'and now we are bringing slowly and carefully home our great soldiers.'"*

que es el mismo orden de palabras por el que pregunté antes en este post. Tengo preferencia por este orden de palabras, pero sólo por las siguientes razones:

1. No rompo la frase verbal (es decir, *estamos* y *trayendo*
   permanecen juntos) y los adverbios (*lenta y cuidadosamente* y *a
   casa*), sigue el verbo.
2. Me adhiero a la regla alemana de colocación de adverbios: tiempo, modo
   y lugar. (No estoy segura si eso se aplica, pero a menudo he
   notado que los adverbios de tiempo a menudo "encabezan" una frase en español y lo hace aquí también con *ahora*.  Así que, quizá los otros hagan lo mismo.)

Dicho esto, debo admitir que *and now we are bringing slowly and carefully home our great soldiers* suena realmente incómoda en inglés. En este ejemplo particular, suena mucho más natural en inglés poner el adverbio de lugar (home) inmediatamente después del verbo (es decir, *... we are bringing home ...*)  o separar la frase verbal (es decir, *... we are slowly and carefully bringing ...*).

Si el orden de las palabras en español no es tan importante y puedo escribir partes de una oración en el orden que quiera (sin la regla cardinal de mantener juntas las partes de una frase verbal), ¿entonces estoy enfatizando ciertos aspectos de una oración a través de mi elección de la colocación de las palabras? Por ejemplo:

1. > "... 'y ahora estamos lenta y cuidadosamente trayendo a nuestros grandes soldados ***a casa***'".
   > "... 'and now we are slowly and carefully bringing our great soldiers ***home***.'"
2. > ... y ahora estamos **trayendo lenta y cuidadosamente** a casa ***a nuestros
   > grandes soldados***.
   > "... 'and now we are **bringing slowly and carefully** home ***our great soldiers***.'"
3. > ... y ahora estamos **trayendo a casa** lenta y cuidadosamente ***a nuestros
   > grandes soldados***.
   > "... 'and now we are **bringing home** slowly and carefully ***our great soldiers***.'"

¿Las tres variaciones españolas que he enumerado son gramaticalmente correctas?  ¿Suenan todas naturales para un hablante nativo de español?  ¿Destaca una como la mejor en términos de orden/construcción de palabras?

*Traducción realizada, en parte, con la versión gratuita del traductor [www.DeepL.com/Translator.](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator.)*

Comment: I suppose you could contemplate bringing slowly and carefully before the verb too. A comma might be needed after now.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence:

"... y ahora estamos lenta y cuidadosamente trayendo a nuestros grandes soldados a casa."

seems to be a literal translation from English and sounds a bit strange in Spanish because we usually don't insert compound adverbial phrases before the verb, or in the middle of a verb phrase, **unless** they are set off by commas:

"... y ahora estamos, lenta y cuidadosamente, trayendo a nuestros grandes soldados a casa."

With simple adverbs of manner, that order will work perfectly to reinforce the meaning of the verb:

- Tú **(muy) bien** sabes que ... (You (very) well know that ...)
- Él **rápidamente** se adaptó a la situación. (He quickly adjusted to the situation.)

Word order is quite free in Spanish, and adverbials are no exception. Adverbials of place and time can appear in different positions and, unlike adverbials of manner which tend to need commas when compound and placed in an anomalous position, those of place and time generally do not. That said, the examples below all work provided that the adverbials of manner are set off by commas. Note should be taken of the fact that in (2) the closing comma will appear after the adverbial of place.

1. "... y ahora estamos, lenta y cuidadosamente, trayendo a nuestros grandes soldados a casa."
2. "... y ahora estamos trayendo, lenta y cuidadosamente a casa, a nuestros grandes soldados."
3. "... y ahora estamos trayendo a casa, lenta y cuidadosamente, a nuestros grandes soldados."

Thus, we have:

1. [adverb of time] traer, [adverb of manner], DO [adverb of place]
2. [adverb of time] traer, [adverb of manner + adverb of place], DO
3. [adverb of time] traer [adverb of place], [adverb of manner], DO

My conclusion is that with the verb "traer" the adverb of place plays a key role (you bring someone somewhere) and will therefore appear either immediately after the verb or after the direct object. This is what makes it appear within the commas in (2) - the adverb of place does not admit being placed after a comma unless the direct object appears first, as in (1).

Final note: The rules above apply to a transitive verb like "traer" and might change in other cases. I think, however, that they may be deemed to be generally applicable.